# How to change splash screen size?

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I'm using WPF on C#, I added a `*.png` image and configure it as a splash screen.

This png file has resolution is 1100x800 pixels, The problem is my application will support many resolution of screens.

So this splash screen with this size will so large for small screen (as 1366x768 screens).

If I scale down size of splash screen, this make it too small for the large screens (as 1920x1080 screens).

So I want to change size of splash screen dynamically for each monitor screen.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. The splash screen is embedded inside the manifest and is shown by .net before any of your code is loaded.

You will need to create a custom window and display it manually. However, any static references will be loaded already - you will still get a delay. This subverts the whole point of having a splash screen.

Consider just choosing the smallest image you will ever need.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this using a PNG, it will always render a fixed size. You should create a custom splash screen. [This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF) has a nice tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you! But this custom splash screen will run when all static references loaded? If it does, as Gusdor said, "This subverts the whole point of having a splash screen"!

Comment: It will only load the code needed to launch the splash screen, depending on how you program it; you should try it out since the performance will be pretty ok.