# Use correct size of WPF SplashScreen for screens with different DPI

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen, highdpi

I'm using the [SplashScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) functionality in my WPF app (e.g. 400x200px PNG file). On screens with standard DPI, SplashScreen is displayed correctly, but on Retina displays or other High-DPI screens it looks very small. It is possible to provide more PNG resources (with different sizes) and choose one based on screen DPI?

My current implememntation (in `App.xaml.cs`):

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen("Resources/Images/splash-screen.png");
        splash.Show(true, true);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change splash screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997173/how-to-change-splash-screen-size)

Comment: It is a similar question, but I will be ok also with solution based on multiple PNG resources instead of scaling single resource.

Comment: From the answers on that page it doesn't appear to be possible using the built-in splash-screen feature. The [Guidelines for splash screens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx) page indicates that you can add 3 specific sizes to support different resolutions but that's for UWP apps on Win10 devices so probably won't work on regular WPF. My suggestion would be to implement it manually e.g. as per the solution on [this page](http://jkshay.com/easily-create-wpf-splash-screen-status-updates-via-mvvm/).